# r studio импорт csv

Tags: r

Подскажите, как импортировать несколько csv в R за раз? нашла такой код, но на выходе получаю все данные в одном столбце, не могу понять, как их разделить по точке с запятой.

```
im = list.files(pattern = "*.csv")
my_data = lapply(im, read_csv)
df <- do.call(rbind, my_data)
```

Comment: CSV - это "Comma-Separated Values", т.е. "Значения, Разделённые Запятой". Если в качестве разделителя используется точка с запятой - это не CSV. Для импорта SSV (Semicolon-Separated Values) используется `read_csv2`. Либо `lapply(im, read.csv, sep=";")`.

Comment: спасибо, получила, что хотела